# Install GUI for Ubuntu server from desktop CD

Tags: installation, server

I have very low internet speed in my home. I need to install GUI for Ubuntu server edition without the use of the internet. I have an Ubuntu desktop CD. How do I do this?

Comment: Try this http://askubuntu.com/a/150148/63025

Answer (score 2):

You can follow these steps *(but, accordingly to [psusi](https://askubuntu.com/users/8500/psusi)'s comment, this only will work with the DVD or Alternate CD versions of Desktop Edition)*

**[1] First step**: add your CD / DVD to the sources list.

- **Option A**: Edit the Source.list and comment all the repositories excepting the CD with:

  `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`
- **Option B**: Use Apt-cdrom

  1. test:  `sudo apt-cdrom --no-act add`
  2. if everything is OK: `sudo apt-cdrom add`
  3. `sudo apt-cdrom ident`
  4. `sudo apt-cdrom -d "your-cdrom-mount-point" -r`

---

**[2] Second step**: update with: `sudo apt-get update`

---

**[3] Third step**: install desktop environment

- **Option A (recommended)**: install a graphical desktop manager without some of the desktop addons like Evolution and OpenOffice, but continue to use the server flavor kernel:

  `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop`
- **Option B**: install a graphical desktop manager with **ALL** desktop addons like Evolution and OpenOffice:

  `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

---

**[4] Fourth and final step:** restore your source list to the previous state

Uncomment everything you had 'commented' before (if you want, comment CD again) with:

`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: This won't work with the desktop cd; you need the dvd or the alternate cd.

Comment: Good to know. I will update the answer

Comment: Someone can explain the reasons for the down votes?