# How do I install KDE or XFCE or LXDE to an Ubuntu 12.04 system with no internet connection?

Tags: kubuntu, xubuntu, kde, lubuntu, internet-connection

How do you install a desktop environment such as KDE without an Internet connection in Ubuntu / Linux Mint?

I want to install KDE 4.8.3 in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS  without an Internet connection?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, Joe! Please remember to accept/upvote the best answer to your question (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as "answered" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

### Offline installation of LXDE, XFCE or KDE on Ubuntu 12.04

- You can install one of the supported variant desktop environments for Ubuntu 12.04 (LXDE, XFCE or KDE) by downloading the **alternate CD** for that variant -- Lubuntu, Xubuntu and Kubuntu respectively. Please be sure to get **32-bit or 64-bit** depending on your existing installation!

> **Direct links to alternate CD ISOs:**
>
> - Kubuntu 12.04 (KDE): [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/12.04/release/kubuntu-12.04-alternate-i386.iso) | [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/12.04/release/kubuntu-12.04-alternate-amd64.iso)
> - Lubuntu 12.04 (LXDE): [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.04/release/lubuntu-12.04-alternate-i386.iso) | [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.04/release/lubuntu-12.04-alternate-amd64.iso)
> - Xubuntu 12.04 (XFCE): [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/12.04/release/xubuntu-12.04-alternate-i386.iso) | [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/12.04/release/xubuntu-12.04-alternate-amd64.iso)
>
> The Alternate CD is required because it actually contains the deb packages needed to install these onto a running system with `apt-get` versus the regular Desktop Live CDs which contain a compressed filesystem.

- Once you download the Alternate CD ISO (32-bit or 64-bit, depending on your Ubuntu installation), burn it to a CD-R. Insert the CD into the target system.
- Open a terminal with `Ctrl-Alt-T`, and type `ls /media`. You will see something in there like `Kubuntu 12.04 LTS i386`.
- Then type `sudo apt-cdrom add /media/Kubuntu` (the first few letters), and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to autocomplete the full name and press enter. `apt` will scan the CD for packages.
- Now type `sudo apt-get update`, and then `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` to install the full KDE desktop environment. (Or `xubuntu-desktop` or `lubuntu-desktop`, respectively, for XFCE or LXDE).
- If you have an internet connection on the machine, please disconnect the Ethernet cable (or disable networking/wireless), because even after you add the CD repositories, `apt-get` may still try to fetch the latest packages over the internet if it detects a connection!