# Not giving me the "try ubuntu" option

Tags: installation, boot, usb

I have created a bootable usb for 12.04 and i placed it in my computer and elected it to boot from flash drive but it is only giving me the option to install and not to try what can i do to get the try it option

Comment: How was called the file you downloaded?

Comment: What application did you use to burn the image?

Answer (score 3):

If you're reaching this screen,

[image: Ubuntu 12.04 - Alternate CD - Boot menu]

it probably means that your USB drive contains the ["alternate"](https://askubuntu.com/q/150202/1859) CD image, which is designed for uncommon situations and intentionally leaves out the Try Ubuntu option.

Start over with one of the "desktop" CD images (`ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-*.iso`) instead and refer to the [instructions on the Ubuntu website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) to put it onto the USB drive.

You should get a boot menu that looks like this:

[image]