# Can the alternative installation file for Lubuntu work as a backup OS stored in a bootable flash drive to retrieve files on a computer?

Tags: boot, lubuntu, crash

I guess that in the case when my Lubuntu on my laptop can't boot for whatever reason, it will be helpful for me to run a live version of Lubuntu out of  a bootable flash drive to retrieve the files on the file systems on my laptop.

I was wondering if the alternative 64-bit installation file [`lubuntu-18.04-alternate-amd64.iso`](https://lubuntu.me/downloads/) is suitable for that purpose? I have a flash drive of 1GB, and that installation file is 717MB the only one which fits into my flash drive.

I have never used the alternative installation file: *will I run into problem if I boot into the Ubuntu in it from a flash drive to retrieve my files on my laptop?*

Comment: The alternate installation .iso is for installation only, and not for running live. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/150202/difference-between-live-cd-and-alternate-cd . I am not sure why you got a drive by down vote or a close vote.

Comment: Thanks.  What are some installations that can run a live OS for me to retrieve the files on my laptop? Prefer installation file size small.

Comment: Any live iso from any Linux OS can do that. You do not really install in that case, you create a bootable usb - https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu . Other distors have other methods. There are recovery specific distros as an alternate to ubuntu - http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/top-5-linux-system-rescue-cds sort of depends on what you want. There are tiny distros also such as tinycore. https://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/

Comment: I am only familiar with Ubuntu , and scared of trying the others that you linked. The only flash drive that I have larger than Ubuntu live installation file (something betw 1GB and 2GB?) is 4GB, and the other flash drive I have is 1GB. Is it possible to use the 4GB flash drive for both a live Ubuntu OS and temporary storage for my other personal files? See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/445443/how-can-i-create-a-bootable-flash-drive-for-lbuntu-and-also-store-temporarily-ot

Comment: It is possible, but now we are sort of getting a bit off topic.

Comment: Thanks. Sry. Is it possible but not common? Is the common practice to make a whole flash drive dedicated to a live OS?

Comment: @Panther: that's not a comment but an answer.  you know the drill: ping me and I'll come back and upvote.

Comment: I think you want a persistent live drive, if you want to both boot from it and save files in it. Standard live drives are read-only. (You can save data temporarily, but those data will disappear, when you shut down or reboot.) You can make such a drive from a Lubuntu desktop iso file (but not from a Lubuntu alternate iso file).

Comment: @sudodus Two drives here. The first is  in the laptop for the dead Lubuntu. The second is in a flash hard drive for a live Lubuntu. I want to boot into the live Lubuntu in flash drive to access the files on the drive in the laptop.

Comment: If you want an Ubuntu family desktop iso file, that is smaller than 1 GB (to fit into your 1 GB USB pendrive), you can get **xubuntu-18.04-core-amd64.iso** which is only 695 MB (663MiB). See [this link](https://unit193.net/xubuntu/core/) provided by one of the Xubuntu team members.

Comment: @sudodus Does it provide file copying programs such as `rsync`?

Comment: Yes, `rsync` is there. All the basic command line program packages are there. Also `tar` is there.

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck :-)